# Weka decimal precision

Tags: java, decimal, classification, weka, precision

After getting very excited by what seemed like excellent results from using the MLP within the Weka GUI on my pricing data, I've coded up a bit of Java that uses an MLP with the same parameters. Here is where the fun starts, the results are completely different, I've now found that this appears to be be due to rounding differences. The GUI rounds to 3 dp, my java code rounds to 5 dp.

I've looked through the manuals but I can't seem to find an option to force the GUI to use 5dp precision on the predicitions it outputs. Does anyone know how I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you would show some code of how you do the output now.

Comment: maybe you have used a different default value for the seed of the random number generator?

Comment: I'm not looking for my code to change I'm trying to understand how to get the standard Weka GUI to increase it's precision for the predicitions. So for example my Java code would output "Predicted: 0.85016 Actual: 0.85041" where as the GUI gives "Predicted: 0.850  Actual: 0.850"

Answer (score 0):

The [Pentaho WEKA Forum](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?195366-Weka-Decimal-Places) says that the number of decimal places in the GUI is fixed. However, in writing the output from the GUI to a file, you can control the number of decimal places.