# WEKA Changing number of decimal places in predictions

Tags: machine-learning, command-line-interface, weka, precision, arff

I'm trying to get precise predictions from WEKA, and I need to increase the number of decimal places that it outputs for its prediction data.

My .arff training set looks like this:

```
@relation TrainSet

@attribute TimeDiff1 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff2 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff3 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff4 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff5 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff6 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff7 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff8 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff9 numeric
@attribute TimeDiff10 numeric
@attribute LBN/Distance numeric
@attribute LBNDiff1 numeric
@attribute LBNDiff2 numeric
@attribute LBNDiff3 numeric
@attribute Size numeric
@attribute RW {R,W}
@attribute 'Response Time' numeric

@data

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,203468398592,0,0,0,32768,R,0.006475
0.004254,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4564742206976,4361273808384,0,0,65536,R,0.011025
0.002128,0.006382,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4585966117376,21223910400,4382497718784,0,4096,R,0.01389
0.001616,0.003744,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4590576115200,4609997824,25833908224,4387107716608,4096,R,0.005276
0.002515,0.004131,0.010513,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,233456156672,-4357119958528,-4352509960704,-4331286050304,32768,R,0.01009
0.004332,0.006847,0.010591,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,312887472128,79431315456,-4277688643072,-4273078645248,4096,R,0.005081
0.000342,0.004674,0.008805,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3773914294272,3461026822144,3540458137600,-816661820928,8704,R,0.004252
0.000021,0.000363,0.00721,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3772221901312,-1692392960,3459334429184,3538765744640,4096,W,0.00017
0.000042,0.000063,0.004737,0.01525,0,0,0,0,0,0,3832104423424,59882522112,58190129152,3519216951296,16384,W,0.000167
0.005648,0.00569,0.006053,0.016644,0,0,0,0,0,0,312887476224,-3519216947200,-3459334425088,-3461026818048,19456,R,0.009504
```

I'm trying to get predictions for the Response Time, which is the right-most column. As you can see, my data goes to the 6th decimal place.

However, WEKA's predictions only go to the 3rd. Here are the results of the file named "predictions":

```
    inst#     actual  predicted      error
        1      0.006      0.005     -0.002 
        2      0.011      0.017      0.006 
        3      0.014      0.002     -0.012 
        4      0.005      0.022      0.016 
        5      0.01       0.012      0.002 
        6      0.005      0.012      0.007 
        7      0.004      0.018      0.014 
        8      0          0.001      0     
        9      0          0.001      0     
       10      0.01       0.012      0.003
```

As you can see, this greatly limits the accuracy of my predictions. For very small numbers less than 0.0005 (like row 8 and 9), they will show up as 0 instead of a more accurate smaller decimal number.

I'm using WEKA on the "Simple Command Line" instead of the GUI. My command to build the model looks like this:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree -M 2 -V 0.00001 -N 3 -S 1 -L -1 -I 0.0 -num-decimal-places 6 \
   -t [removed path]/TrainSet.arff \
   -T [removed path]/TestSet.arff \
   -d [removed path]/model1.model > \
   [removed path]/model1output
```

([removed path]: I just removed the full pathname for privacy)

As you can see, I found this "-num-decimal-places" switch for creating the model.

Then I use the following command to make the predictions:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree \
    -T [removed path]/LUN0train.arff \
    -l [removed path]/model1.model -p 0 > \
    [removed path]/predictions
```

I can't use the "-num-decimal places" switch here because WEKA doesn't allow it in this case for some reason. "predictions" is my wanted predictions file.

So I do these two commands, and it doesn't change the number of decimal places in the prediction! It's still only 3.

I've already looked at this answers, [Weka decimal precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729959/weka-decimal-precision/40813817#40813817), and this answer on the [pentaho forum](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/195366-Weka-Decimal-Places/),  but no one gave enough information to answer my question. These answers hinted that changing the number of decimal places might not be possible? but I just want to be sure.

Does any one know of an option to fix this? Ideally a solution would be on the command line, but if you only know how to do it in the GUI, that's ok.

Comment: If you're the same maranathaman who asked this question on the Weka mailing list, it's received what looks like an authoritative answer there. Do you want to update your answer here with the info from the Weka list?

Comment: @nekomatic Sure, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured a work around, which is to simply scale/multiply the data by 1000, and then get your predictions, and then multiply it back to 1/1000 when done to get the original scale. Kinda outside the box, but it works.

EDIT: An alternative way to do it: Answer from Peter Reutemann from http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Changing-decimal-point-precision-td43393.html:

> This has been around for a long time. ;-) "-p" is the really
>   old-fashioned way of outputting the predictions. Using the
>   "-classifications" option, you can specify what format the output is
>   to be in (eg CSV). The class that you specify with that option has to
>   be derived from
>   "weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput":
>   http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/output/prediction/AbstractOutput.html
>
> Here is an example of using 12 decimals for the prediction output
>   using Java:
>   https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/wekaexamples/src/main/java/wekaexamples/classifiers/PredictionDecimals.java